# \varnothing or \emptyset not at the end of the line

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I'd like to place either a `\varnothing` or a `\emptyset` symbol in my text, but every time I try, the symbol appears at the end of the line and not just behind the text where it needs to be.
How can I change that ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please post a [working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) of code that gives rise to the undesirable behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  we really need more information -- a symbol like `\varnothing` or `\emptyset` doesn't go to the end of a line all by itself.  please make a "minimum (non)working example" (an "mwe") starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and just enough other information to demonstrate the problem.  you may even find out what is causing the problem while you are constructing the mwe, although you may still need help with solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
sbhfgjksd safjksdhfjk sahjkfhsjk fsabf jksabfkjsbfk 
sfalsjfj, lnsadf snfjklsaflhwuioerhs lsdhfsda sadf 
safdlsalf nsafdjnsaklfsaklfd safdj\hfill$\emptyset$

sbhfgjksd safjksdhfjk sahjkfhsjk fsabf jksabfkjsbfk 
sfalsjfj, lnsadf snfjklsaflhwuioerhs lsdhfsda sadf 
safdlsalf nsafdjnsaklfsaklfd safdj\hfill$\varnothing$
\end{document}
```

which will put the symbols directly at the end of the lines.